# Layer output of a pre-trained model produces different outputs unexpectedly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, vgg-net

I have a `(1, 224, 224, 3)` sized numpy array named `content_image`. That is the size of VGG network input.

When I transfer `content_image` to input of VGG network as illustrated below:

```
model = vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor=K.variable(content_image), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in model .layers:
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv2':
        model_output = layer.output
```

this seems to produce outputs in scale of `[0, 1]`:

```
[0.06421799 0.07012904 0.         ... 0.         0.05865938
    0.        ]
   [0.21104832 0.27097407 0.         ... 0.         0.
    0.        ] ...
```

On the other hand, when I apply the following approach based on the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/) (extracting features from an arbitrary intermediate layer with VGG19):

```
from keras.models import Model
base_model = vgg19.VGG19(weights='imagenet'), include_top=False) 
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block5_conv2').output)
model_output = model.predict(content_image)
```

This approach seems to produce outputs differently.

```
[ 82.64436     40.37433    142.94958    ...   0.
     27.992153     0.        ]
   [105.935936    91.84446      0.         ...   0.
     86.96397      0.        ] ...
```

The both approaches use the same network with same weights, and transfer same numpy array (`content_image`) as inputs but they produce different outputs. I expect that they should produce same results.

Comment: Different layers, different outputs. That's totally normal. ---- This line does nothing: `model_output = layer.output`. Did you mean `model.output`? I really don't think you should do this that way, who knows the amount of hidden bugs for trying to hack what is expected.

Comment: Just use the second (and correct) approach.

Comment: @Daniel, respond to your second answer, you cannot find gradients with second way. First one works well but second one does not. I wonder the root cause.

Comment: @Daniel, respond to your first answer, the both approach find the same layer's output - block5_conv2. the layer is mentioned in both code blocks.

Comment: @johncasey could you please add the code you use to evaluate and print the `model_output` in the first approach?

Comment: @today, in second approach it produces numpy array and I just run the command print(model_output). But in the first approach it is in type of Tensor. That's why, I am using following code:

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    v1 = sess.run(model_output)
    print(v1)

Comment: @johncasey Would you please confirm that the issue was caused by creating a new session as I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would get the same result if you use the session (implicitly) created by Keras in your first approach:

```
sess = K.get_session()
with sess.as_default():
    output = model_output.eval()
    print(output)
```

I think by creating a new session and using `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` and `sess.run(init)` you are changing the values of variables. In general, don't create a new session and instead use the session created by Keras (unless you have good reasons to do otherwise).

Comment: yes, that was the problem. now, it is solved. thank you!